# Automatic fill Pojo using annotation with orientdb

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, orientdb

first point is I am useing orientdb version 2.1.7.

I try to realize a project with orientdb inlcuding jpa. As described in this [doc](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Object-2-Record-Java-Binding.html) automatic loading, saving and deleting works for simple POJOs.

But there are two points that did not work out.

1. I want to make a property unique. I know it works when I do it programmatically like this:
   `OrientVertexType vertexType = graph.createVertexType(vertexName);
   vertexType.createProperty("id", OType.STRING);
   vertexType.createIndex("ididx", OClass.INDEX_TYPE.UNIQUE, "id");`

But is there a way to do this via annotations? The JPA annotaion (@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)) seems not to work.

2. I have two VertexTypes which are connected by Edges. Also I want that the collection is automatic loaded via annotation. Example (getters and setters are not listed):
   The User Object:

`public class MyUser implements iMyUser { 
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Set<MyGroup> groups;
    ...
}`

The Group Object:

`public class MyGroup implements iMyGroup {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    ...
}`

In JPA you can add something like `@JoinTable(name = "table", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "colname") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "colname") })` to the groups property in MyUser and when you call the methode `getGroups()` you get the groups which have a relation. Is there a annotation in orientdb that supports such an behaviour?
I think [this](https://github.com/tinkerpop/frames/wiki/Getting-Started) (@Adjacency) might be a solution but till now I didn't have any success in implementing it.

Also is there a list or something which annotations are supported?

Regards,
foo

Answer (score 0):

The second point is possible with tinkerpop frames. @Adjacency annotation for direct relations between objects and @[GremlinGroovy](https://github.com/tinkerpop/frames/wiki/Java-Handler) for queries. It is a bit strange to have the annotation at the interface, but however it works.

For the first point there might be no solution via annotation, but you can create unique index via the orientdb backend.